# Como implementar "foreign key" usando arquitetura de Micro Serviços? Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, microsserviços

Estou tentando montar um sistema usando a arquitetura de micro serviços, me deparei com o problema sobre dependência, no caso como implementar `chave estrangeira` usando essa arquitetura? eu estou utilizando o Django

Exemplo

A classe `pedido` que será um serviço está vinculado a um cliente, que também será serviço, como implementar isso na arquitetura microservicos já que ambos estão fisicamente desacopladas?

normalmente eu declararia assim

```
class Pedido:
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente)
```

e acessaria um cliente de um pedido assim :

```
p = Pedido.objects.filter().first()
p.cliente.nome
```

Usando a arquitetura de miroservicos eu não poderia declarar dessa forma já que a classe `Cliente` não existiria no serviço `Pedido`

Comment: Eu não tenho experiência com micro serviços, mas se entendi bem você deseja desacoplar `Pedido` de `Cliente`, de modo que eles possam residir em sistemas separados (talvez em BDs diferentes, ou mesmo em servidores diferentes), é isso? Se sim, não conheço nada pronto no Django que faça isso, creio que você teria que armazenar no campo `cliente` não uma chave estrangeira mas um valor simples (inteiro? string?) que identificasse unicamente aquele cliente mesmo entre serviços diferentes. Então, para obter o cliente associado àquele pedido, você faria um `Cliente.objects.get(xxx=p.cliente).nome`.

Comment: Isso, é, realmente não tem muita informação ainda de como fazer isso na prática, na teoria a gente ver de carrada artigos dizendo o que é, mostrando as vantagens mas mostrando um exemplo de implementação é difícil, nesse caso ai eu perderia uma boa parte das vantagens do ORM do django, teria que fazer um trabalho bem manual.

Nao tenho mais tempo, vou fazer monolítico e lá na frente a gente muda a arquitetura, vlw

Answer (score 3):

Não leve muito ao pé da letra esta questão de descoplar pois corre o risco de fazê-lo no lugar errado.
Tente trazer a idéia de micro serviço para o mundo real e veja o que acontece. Imagine a seguinte situação:

1. Você entra em um restaurante e senta em uma MESA;
2. O *garçom* vem e tira o PEDIDO e anota o número da MESA;
3. O *garçom*, leva o PEDIDO até a *cozinha* que prepara o PEDIDO e toca a *campainha* quando estiver
   pronto;
4. O *garçom* serve o prato na MESA;
5. Você consome o PEDIDO e pede ao *garçom* a CONTA;
6. O *garçom* vai a té o caixa, pede a CONTA e te entrega;
7. Você vai até o *caixa*, paga a CONTA e vai embora.

Veja que neste caso os micro serviços estão representados por *garçom*, *cozinha* e *caixa*.

O garçom não sabe nada sobre fazer comida, a cozinha não sabe nada sobre servir e o caixa só sabe que tem que cobrar, ou seja, eles estão DESACOPLADOS e funcionam independentes.

Mas veja que todos eles tem a visão do cliente(representado pela MESA) e do PEDIDO. Aqui fica bem claro que você não deve separar estas entidades e o que acontece neste tipo de arquitetura é a  REDUNDÂNCIA dos dados pois cada serviço tem que ter uma cópia do PEDIDO com o número da MESA.

Portanto, microserviços apesar de independentes e assíncronos tem que guardar as mesmas informações e para garantir isso tem que ter uma forma de comunicação eficiente (sockets é um bom exemplo).

Se você ler o artigo do [Martin Fowler](http://www.pedromendes.com.br/2016/01/02/microservicos/%22Martin%20Fowler%22)  vai ver que ele recomenda iniciar monolítico mesmo e criar micro serviços somente quando necessário. Fazer isso no início é perda de  tempo.